# How to make getter return something depending on the argument?

Tags: java, getter

I'm writing a code to practice getters and setters, and I've run into the following situation:

I created 5 products and declared them in a class as private. I want my getter to return the name of the product based on the argument the method receives. Like, `public String getProduct(String product) {}`. So far, I've written as follows:

```
class Products {
    private String p1 = "Mocha", p2 = "Latte", p3 = "Cappuccino", p4 = "Frappuccino", p5 = "Cafe au Lait";
    private int priceP1 = 8, priceP2 = 5, priceP3 = 10, priceP4 = 13, priceP5 = 3;

    public String getProduct(String product) {
        return this.product;

    } 

}
```

What I thought was a getter being used like `public String getProducts(p1);`, which would return `Mocha`. However, when I compile the code, it says `cannot find symbol - symbol: variable product`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Oh dear. That's not at all how it works. You should have a `Product` class that contains the name and the price for a single item, not a `Products` class that contains everything in separate variables and a franken-getter that doesn't work because you've misunderstood how variables are used in Java. Go read [some tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: What @Kayaman said, and about the cannot find symbol; `product` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Thanks guys. Will do.

Comment: Sorry, but there is a misconception on your end: this is not a free tutor service. You have trouble with *basic* java syntax. The answer: read a good book/tutorial and *learn* how correct syntax looks like. There are various things in your code what would need fixing. But as said: this isn't programming school.

Comment: @GhostCat I get it, and I didn't come up here saying "hey guys, I want a program running butter smooth with getters and setters, please give me the code". I did something on my own, what I genuinely thought was mostly correct, and asked a question about what I thought was the mistake. I _am_ reading books about it, but learning involves mistakes. I bet you all been there. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I like your creativity, but unfortunately, Java wasn't designed to work that way. As others have pointed out the reasons, I won't delve into them. But I would suggest for you to use an IDE(Eclipse is Open Source, try that). The problem that you faced is a compile time error and the IDE would help you identify and fix them even before running the code.

Comment: @Nishit I do use it (NetBeans, tho), but I'm currently at work and with free time to spare, so I have to appeal to Notepad and Online Java Compilers. Thanks for _actually_ providing a useful answer. It would appear the least reputation someone has, the more polite and human they are.

Comment: @LuisEduardo, everyone is here to help and grow. I would take all answers constructively and grow technically. Don't let some bad taste keep you away from SO. This is a great place to clear your doubts :)

Comment: @Nishit It is, indeed. When there are people willing to help and clear. Thanks once more. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you havent declared any 'product' in your main class, so when you do `return this.product;` you'll get the error you are saying.
As Kayaman said, you should learn some tutorials about Java variables.
But, you can try this as a simple simple tutorial:

```
public static class Products {
        HashMap<String, String> productList = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public Products() {
            productList.put("p1", "Mocha");
            productList.put("p2","Latte");
        }

        public String getProductName(String productID){
            return productList.get(productID);
        }
    }
```

Ussage:

```
Products p=new Products();
System.out.println(p.getProductName("p2"));
```

Console:

```
Latte
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Product` with instance fields and then use a List e.g.
Like:

```
public class Product {
    private Type type;
    private int price;

    public Product(Type type, int price) {
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public enum Type {
        Mocca, Latte, Cappuccino;
    }
}
```

then you can use it like:

```
List<Product> products = new Arraylist();
products.add(new Product(Type.Latte, 5));
```

Btw, you can start here to get the basics of Objects and Classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html